# Gorm query lasts over a minute before successfully committing

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, go, go-gorm

I am writing a simple golang app with controller-service-repository architecture.

My repository has access to database and is in charge of inserting records in database.

After I make a request in Postman, it lasts over a minute and it successfully inserts a record in database. I also tried giving the controller direct access to database and same thing occurs.

I even tried writing a simple handler that establishes connection to database and performs a query and that works just fine, but if I use this architecture something is slowing down the performance.

If anyone has an idea what might be a problem, please let me know.

Here is the code of my main function as well as the controller, service and repository :

main :

```
func main() {
    r := setupRouter()

    pgInstance := db2.ConnectToDatabase()

    repo := repository.NewRepository(pgInstance)

    service := service2.NewService(repo)

    c := controller2.NewController(service)

    routes.InitializeRoutes(r, c)

    // Listen and Server in 0.0.0.0:8080
    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

controller :

```
type Controller struct {
    service service.Service
}

func NewController(service service.Service) Controller {
    return Controller{
        service: service,
    }
}
```

service :

```
type Service struct {
    repository repository.Repository
}

func NewService(repo repository.Repository) Service {
    return Service{
        repository: repo,
    }
}
```

repository :

```
type Repository struct {
    db *gorm.DB
}

func NewRepository(db *gorm.DB) Repository {
    return Repository{
        db: db,
    }
}

func (r Repository) Db() *gorm.DB {
    return r.db
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After weeks of digging I found the issue what is causing the problem.

I have a BeforeSave hook that encrypted users password.I set performance cost too high.

For those who did same mistake as me, cost around 10 is just fine (20 is a no go).

Comment: OK, upvoted: more specific than my general answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the same files, with some additions to better measure and debug any performance issue:

#### main.go

> Something is slowing down the performance.

Then I would start and enable [Go's built-in profiler](https://go.dev/blog/pprof). This helps in understanding where the application is spending time and can be used to identify bottlenecks.
You can also add a `LoggerMiddleware` is added to log the incoming HTTP requests, for monitoring the performance of incoming requests.

Make sure the [database connection pool](https://gorm.io/docs/generic_interface.html#Connection-Pool) is configured to ensure that the pool has enough connections to handle your requests. Setting maximum open connections, idle connections, and connection lifetime helps in managing resources efficiently.

Activate also [GORM's LogMode](https://gorm.io/docs/logger.html), enabled to print SQL queries to the console for debugging purposes. This helps in examining the actual SQL queries being generated and executed against the database.

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Profiling: Enabling Go's built-in profiler to see where the time is being spent in your application.
    go func() {
        log.Println(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:6060", nil))
    }()

    // Setting up the router
    r := gin.Default()

    // Middleware for logging requests: This middleware logs the incoming HTTP requests,
    // for debugging and monitoring performance.
    r.Use(LoggerMiddleware())

    // Database Connection: Establish connection to the database using GORM.
    db, err := gorm.Open(...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Configure connection pool: GORM uses a connection pool to manage connections to the database.
    // This configuration ensures that the pool has enough connections to handle your requests.
    sqlDB, err := db.DB()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    sqlDB.SetMaxOpenConns(10)
    sqlDB.SetMaxIdleConns(5)
    sqlDB.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Minute * 5)

    // Query Optimization: Enabling GORM's LogMode to print SQL queries to the console for debugging purposes.
    // This is useful to check the actual SQL queries being generated by GORM and executed against the database.
    db = db.Debug()

    // Initialize repository, service, controller
    repo := NewRepository(db)
    service := NewService(repo)
    controller := NewController(service)

    // Initialize routes
    InitializeRoutes(r, controller)

    // Listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
    r.Run(":8080")
}

// LoggerMiddleware is a middleware function for logging HTTP requests.
func LoggerMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        startTime := time.Now()
        c.Next()
        log.Println("Request:", c.Request.Method, c.Request.URL, "Duration:", time.Since(startTime))
    }
}
```

#### repository.go

The `repository.go` file contains the repository layer of the application. The repository is responsible for interacting with the database. It abstracts the database access and contains the CRUD operations.
You can add [**transaction management**](https://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html) by updating the `CreateRecord` function: this ensures that if there is an error during the creation of the record, the transaction is rolled back. Proper management of transactions is important to avoid contention and potential performance issues.

```golang
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "log"
)

type Repository struct {
    db *gorm.DB
}

// NewRepository initializes a new repository with a database connection.
func NewRepository(db *gorm.DB) Repository {
    return Repository{
        db: db,
    }
}

// Db returns the database connection.
func (r Repository) Db() *gorm.DB {
    return r.db
}

// CreateRecord inserts a new record into the database.
// Transaction Management: This function uses a transaction with rollback in case of an error.
// Long-running transactions can cause contention and slow down the performance, so it is good to manage them properly.
func (r Repository) CreateRecord(record interface{}) {
    tx := r.db.Begin()
    if err := tx.Create(&record).Error; err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        log.Println("Error inserting record:", err)
        return
    }
    tx.Commit()
}
```

#### service.go

The `service.go` file contains the service layer of the application, that is the business logic and can interact with the repository for database access or make external API calls: add a [**timeout**](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-complete-guide-to-golang-net-http-timeouts/).
The `ExternalAPICall` function is an example of making an external API call with a timeout. Setting a timeout is important to avoid waiting indefinitely, which can block resources and negatively affect performance.

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "log"
)

type Service struct {
    repository Repository
}

// NewService initializes a new service with the given repository.
func NewService(repo Repository) Service {
    return Service{
        repository: repo,
    }
}

// ExternalAPICall makes an external API call with a timeout.
// External API Calls: If your service layer is making calls
// to external APIs or services, it s important to set timeouts 
// to avoid waiting indefinitely. 
// This could otherwise block resources and slow down the performance of your application.
func (s Service) ExternalAPICall() {
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
    }
    resp, err := client.Get("http://example.com")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error fetching data:", err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    // Process response
}
```

#### controller.go

The `controller.go` file contains the controller layer of the application, responsible for handling HTTP requests and responses. It can delegate business logic to the service layer and is responsible for constructing the HTTP responses.
While there are no specific performance-related changes, make sure that proper [error handling](https://go.dev/blog/error-handling-and-go) and response construction should be managed here to ensure the efficient operation of the application.

```golang
package main

type Controller struct {
    service Service
}

// NewController initializes a new controller with the given service.
func NewController(service Service) Controller {
    return Controller{
        service: service,
    }
}

// Define your handler functions here. This is where you will handle HTTP requests and responses.
// The controller is responsible for handling HTTP requests and can delegate business logic to the service layer.
// Proper error handling and response construction should be managed here.
```